# How to properly add custom view to the toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar

I am using toolbar with extended height (56dp + 80dp) and want to add EditText to the bottom of the toolbar. The problem I have is that EditText DOES NOT expands itself to the right edge, like in picture below:

[image]

The code looks like below:

**toolbar_edit_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Title"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Adding layout to toolbar:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity.getActionBarToolbar().getContext());
    mToolbarLayout = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_edit_text, null);
    Toolbar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    mActivity.getActionBarToolbar().addView(mToolbarLayout, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Actually I made like descibed in the answers  -  did add custom layout just below toolbar. I'm afraid there's no other solution right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the toolbar behaves more or less like a LinearLayout, even when it doesn't extend it.

If I'm right, you wouldn't be able to use "two rows" like you intend.

Maybe you can take that EditView out of the toolbar, or alternatively, use `ActionBar` (With the 'X' icon and the actions) and below a toolbar with the EditText.

Comment: can you provide a sample ?

Answer (score -2):

You can add a custom layout with EditText below the Toolbar, with the same background color.

Comment: No. The toolbar has a drop shadow so this will look ugly.

Comment: definitely bad decision. Android OS provides you a variety of methods, don't try to hunting squirrel with a howitzer