# Overflow menu changes custom Toolbar layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I have an Activity with a custom `Toolbar`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

    < !-- More content, including search box -->

      </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It looks like this in the preview:

[image]

But it looks like this on the device:

[image]

It seems like the overflow menu is changing the layout.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Have you tried setting the SearchView Maxwidth to `(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some similar questions have been asked without an answer:
[How to properly add custom view to the toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573600/how-to-properly-add-custom-view-to-the-toolbar)

Instead I just put the search view **below** the toolbar, not within it.  I matched the background colors.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:logo="@drawable/ic_restaurant_white_24px"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:titleMarginStart="24dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_bar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="12dp">
```

Comment: Using an `AppBarLayout` would be another solution - would come in handy if you want to hide either the title or search once the user stars scrolling.